# Cronjob Javascript, how to fire job limited times? ( set counter and max limit )

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I'm new to Cronjob and looking for a way to fire it with interval but only 5 times.
Im firing an API call with cron and do not want to loop it.
Is it possible to set a counter and max limit of how many times cron has been executed?
or is there another better way of making delayed API calls with nodejs 5 times during 5 min ?

Comment: I assume you mean you've configured the system's cron to run a node.js script right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if crontab allows to have count. Rather you can write a wrapper program which will be called by the cron job. The wrapper can store the count of how many times the api is called.(save count to a file/database). Based on the count, wrapper can decide whether to call api or not.Then schedule your wrapper cron to run every 5 mins(whatever the interval that you need).

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, we end up dropping cron at all. Turns out cron is more time-oriented rather than count, but best workaround was storing counter outside of cron and checking count as the first thing in cron.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) and [clearInterval](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) for this purpose and keep a counter of the number of times you've called the api. For example:

```js
// Set this to whatever you wish. For one minute interval this will be 60000
const intervalDuration = 5000;

function callApi(count) {
    console.log("Calling api: count:", count);
    /* Call API here... */
}

function startCallingApi(callCount) {
    
    let context = { count: 0 };
    callApi(++context.count);
    let timeout = setInterval((context) => { 
        callApi(++context.count);
        if (context.count >= callCount) {
            console.log("Call count reached, clearing interval...");
            clearInterval(timeout);
        }
    }, intervalDuration, context);

}

startCallingApi(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

please use https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron, using this will be much simpler and scalable